# How to fix error from structmember.h when compiling with g++

Tags: c, python-3.x, g++, header-files

I made a python script that I wanted to compile to an executable. I used cython first, to create a .c file and then I wanted to compile that to an executable with g++. This however causes an error stating that something in structmember.h (which is a header file that comes with python) is apparently wrong.

I have tried to find other people with the same problem, but I couldn't.

I used this to compile:

g++ Training_set.c -o Training_set.exe

The error i got was:

Training_set.c:17362:26: fatal error: structmember.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
structmember.h:21:5 error: 'Py_ssize_t" does not name a type
structmember.h:67:11 error: expected constructor, destructor or type conversion before '(' token
structmember.h:68:17 error: expected constructor, destructor or type conversion before 'Pymember_SetOne'

Comment: Is structmember.h in the current directory?

Comment: Yes it is, I checked.

Comment: It looks like there's a syntax error in structmember.h. Have you looked at the error message and taken a look at the lines listed?

Comment: well no, since they are from the python3.7 installation i had figured it would be free of errors.
i'll take a look and see if i can find anything though

Comment: So I get one of the error messages, it's simply that a variable is declared without a type, the others i dont understand. The problem is that i dont know what the header file is supposed to do as it is part of the standard python installation as i said above

Comment: Did you copy this file out from where it is normally used? Are you sure you're doing this correctly?

Comment: Well originally, I tried compiling the c file from desktop, but it couldnt find any header files there, so i moved it to python37-32/include, as the header files that the program needed were there. This is the first time i tried compiling a c file to executable so i have no idea wether im doing it right

Comment: your compiling a 'C' file, so why are you using a 'C++' compiler?  They are two different languages

Comment: I looked online on how to compile a c file to executable, and multiple websites stated that installing mingw and using g++ to compile it. I might've read them wrong though. Would you perhaps know a good C compiler?

Comment: 'a good C compiler.?  Yes, `gcc`

Comment: ok, i'll try that, thanks!

Comment: It is a very poor programming practice to have files that are huge.  The file:  `Training_set.c` is, per the error message, more than 17 thousand lines.

Comment: Well the c file was generated using cython, which i then wanted to compile to an executable, so I didn't write it directly. Also, i tried using gcc, and it states that the header file structmember.h doesn't exist, even though it does (similar to the error message in the question)

Answer (score 0):

So i managed to fix my problem, somehow if I put all header files in a subdirectory and provide the path to them with -I it does work.